# upgrade phonegap 1.0.0 to 2.0.1

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, cordova

I'm using phonegap 1.0.0 and I want to upgrade straight forward to 2.0.1.
Will I have to go all the way and upgrade from 1.0.0 -> 1.0.1-> .. -> 2.0.1.

[I've found this tutorial](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_upgrading_ios_index.md.html)

BUT it doesn't say if you can upgrade straight to 2.0.1 from 1.0.0

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Yes I had, it seems that the tutorial is the easiest and the efficient way to upgrade. It's clever to do it via a git, and make branches. Goodluck!

Comment: Hi Elad, I am facing the same problem. I have an iOS application based  on 1.4.1 phonegap, I want to upgrade to the latest one. Do I have to go all the way through from 1.4.1 -> 1.5 -> 1.6, or I can just upgrade straight to the latest version.

Comment: No you don't have to.. You can upgrade straight to 2.0.1 Please follow the steps in PG tutorial. If you'll have any problems don't hesitate to send me a message. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a go.

Having said that here's how I would do it.

1. Check your code into git
2. Upgrade to 2.0.1

Then, if you have any difficulties simply rollback. Make sure you use branches to test things out if you're experimenting.

Comment: I didn't understand, simply install phonegap 2.0.1 and remove my code into a new project?